# Assigning variable amounts of new Objects

Tags: java

I am trying to create a JMenu using names grabbed from tables of a database, so the amount of JMenu items is going to be variable.

```
public static JMenuBar drawMenuBar(){
    ArrayList List = grabSQLTableNames();
    JMenuBar menu = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu contracts = new JMenu("Contracts");
            //from here I am a bit stuck on how to add new JMenuItems to the Menu
}
```

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```
for (int i = 0; i < List.size(); i++) {
    JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(List.get(i));
    contracts.add(item);
}
```

Also, I highly recommend changing `List` to `list`